# How to write MongoDB Realm Schema?

Tags: ios, swift, mongodb, realm, schema

I'm trying to enable Sync with MongoDB Realm on my iOS app. The app already uses Realm DB, but I'm having trouble creating the schemas for my classes due to some less primitive variables. How would you write the following classes as schema (I'm mostly having trouble with List<Assignment> and the LinkingObjects variables)?

```
class Course: Object{

    @objc dynamic var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var _partitionKey: String = ""

    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

    var days = List<String>()
    let assignments = List<Assignment>()
}

class Assignment: Object{
    @objc dynamic var _id: ObjectId = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var _partitionKey: String = ""

    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

    var parentCourse = LinkingObjects(fromType: Course.self, property: "assignments")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Realm, you don't need to 'write schemas' - it's done for you based on the properties of your classes.

For example, when an Realm object is defined in your app, when the app first Sync's to MongoDB Realm Cloud the objects schema is auto-generated. So for example let say I have an app that tracks people and their dogs. If I create the following Object in my app

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var _partitionKey = ""

    @objc dynamic var name = ""
}
```

and run the app, as soon as the app 'speaks' to MongoDB Realm, an object will be created on the server and in your local file with schema based on those Person properties. Nothing more is required or even needed

On the topic of primitives, Realm Collections do not support primitives (very well).

**EDIT:** Release 10.7 added support for filters/queries as well as aggregate functions on primitives so the below info is no longer completely valid. However, it's still something to be aware of.

So they should be avoided. If you want to store objects in Lists, create a Realm object with the primitive as the property.

In your question you have

```
var days = List<String>()
```

this should be changed to

```
class DayClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var date = ""
}

let days = List<DayClass>()
```

Realm does not support queries on a List of primitives and also doesn't support aggregative function on primitives (yet)

What that means is by storing another object within the List, you can use functions like .sum, .min, .max, .count etc. on those objects.

You code is very close and LinkingObjects are perfect. So just a slight change for the List and everything should work as is.